# Grails: Saving domain models with GORM inside an async task

Tags: grails, asynchronous, grails-orm

I'm on Grails 2.3.5 and I'm saving data with gorm inside a task block.
When saving the domain model the task hangs.

Here an excerpt:

```
task {
   def j = new Job()
   j.name = "test"
   j.save()

   println "saved !"  // never get here 
}
```

Any idea on how to save domain models inside a task block ?

Thanks
Luca

Comment: Provide more context. It is a bit hard to understand what u r talking about. Thanks!

Comment: Validation error maybe?  try `j.save(flush:true, failOnError:true)`  I wouldn't recommend those for production but they might help with flushing out issues.

Answer (score 3):

I'm posting here the solution:

```
task {
    Job.withNewSession {
        def j = new Job()
        j.name = "test"
        j.save()
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the variation below.  It's worth noting that there are nuances to be aware of concerning async threads and Hibernate sessions.  See [this section](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/async.html#asyncGorm) in the ref docs for more.

```
Job.async.task {
   def j = new Job()
   j.name = "test
   j.save()
   ...
}
```

Comment: This is not working, but you pointed me in the right direction. I found that `task {Job.withNewSession {` did the trick... Thanks